# rxjs: how to evenly space rendering of responses via Observables

Tags: rxjs

[image]

I'm working on a turn-based game in Angular that communicates to a backend via a socket.io implementation. In my component, I am listening for several types of communication from the server, each communication gives information on how to update my view to reflect the current state of the data in the server.

Right now, updates are immediately applied to the component's data. However I'd prefer to render each update with some delay in-between, so that the user has time to see the effect of each update.

(See my image at top for essentially what I'm trying to do)

I believe that I would achieve this via the subscribeOn operator, but unsure of how to specify my 'interval' n.

```
const example = Rx.Observable
  .create(observer => {
    observer.next(0);
    observer.next(1);
    observer.next(2);
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next(3);
      observer.next(4);
      observer.complete();
    }, 2500);
  });

const source = example
  .subscribeOn(Scheduler.timeout);

source.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Can you show some code? What do you currently have that doesn't work?

Comment: What will happen if 4 is never received?

Comment: It seems that there are 2 separate problems: spread emissions evenly over time and force proper order. Both are very interesting and rather non-trivial. I would suggest to split the question into two.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak - separated - other post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351734/rxjs-how-to-order-responses-via-observables

Comment: @Lansana - my attempted code added.

Comment: @estus - requirements for that scenario added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351734/rxjs-how-to-order-responses-via-observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *concatMap* operator as follows:

```js
const nInterval = 500;

const example$ = Rx.Observable.from([0, 1, 2])
  .concat(Rx.Observable.from([3,4]).delay(2500));

const source$ = example$
  .concatMap(item => 
    Rx.Observable.of(item)
      .concat(
         Rx.Observable.of('ignored')
           .delay(nInterval)
           .ignoreElements()
      )
  );

source$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it would be a bit more readable if you used the `timer` operator like this:
`concatMapTo(Rx.Observable.timer(1000), (x, y) => x)`.

Comment: Is there a way to use a TestScheduler to create an example that better matches the example in the picture? Looks like rxjs4 has a TestScheduler that would do the trick (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/testing/testscheduler.md) but having difficulty finding a rxjs5 equivalent.